# Origin: Can I use variable for a value of environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, openshift, openshift-origin

I am running MYSQL service in my project which creates these environment variables such as below so that application can leverage it to connect to the database.

```
MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST
MYSQL_PORT
MYSQL_USER
MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

But my application container only database host details from these below variables.

```
RDS_HOST
RDS_PORT
RDS_USER
RDS_PASSWORD
```

Now, how can I make my application to use MYSQL env variables?

Is it possible to create a environment variable like this?

```
RDS_HOST=$MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST
```

I did try this but doesn't work.

Comment: If those environment variables are being set already, they must have been set in the deployment config for the application. Just go in and edit the deployment configuration and change the names of the environment variables used. You can do this in the web console by going to the deployment and the environment variables. How did you setup the deployment of this application in the first place?

Comment: deploying the image from Artifactory. I don't see MYSQL env variables in deployment config

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the ``MYSQL_`` environment variables? if they are from the database deployment, just create the environment variables you want in your application deployment config with the names you need and copy the values from the environment variables in the database deployment config.